# How and when to generate new a access token?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am working in Spring Boot with a client API that has an access token that expires in 1 hour and a refresh token that expires in 31 days. Now, I want to call an endpoint `doSomething` via Spring Boot itself. I can generate a new access token every single time I make a request. But these would be unnecessary requests to the client which are not needed.

Is there a way to generate a new access token only when the existing access token has expired? Is this a good practice?

If yes, how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager** will take care of refreshing your access token for you, assuming you get a refresh token along with your access token.  The doco for OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager is at

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2client

When configuring your OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager, make sure you have included **refreshToken** in the OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider...

```
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .authorizationCode()
                    .refreshToken()
                    .build();

    DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                    clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    // Assuming the `username` and `password` are supplied as `HttpServletRequest` parameters,
    // map the `HttpServletRequest` parameters to `OAuth2AuthorizationContext.getAttributes()`
    authorizedClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(contextAttributesMapper());

    return authorizedClientManager;
}
```

You then use the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager to get the access token.  The sample from the spring doco is below...

```
@Controller
public class OAuth2ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Authentication authentication,
                        HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                        HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {

        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("okta")
                .principal(authentication)
                .attributes(attrs -> {
                    attrs.put(HttpServletRequest.class.getName(), servletRequest);
                    attrs.put(HttpServletResponse.class.getName(), servletResponse);
                })
                .build();
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest);

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();

        ...

        return "index";
    }
}
```

If the current accessToken has expired, this will automatically request a new accessToken using the previously obtained refreshToken.

Comment: Hi, is there a need for  us to manually configure to included refreshToken in the OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider. By default, out of the box, will spring boot do for us?